# "IndexError: list index out of range" while charging MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, feed

I get the following error code while executing my Code. The error does not occur immediately - it occurs randomly after 2-7 hours. Until the error occurs there is no problem to stream the online feeds and write them in a DB.

**Error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\MySQL_finalversion\RSS_common_FV.py", line 78, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Python27\MySQL_finalversion\RSS_common_FV.py", line 63, in main
feed_iii = feed_load_iii(feed_url_iii)
File "C:\Python27\MySQL_finalversion\RSS_common_FV.py", line 44, in feed_load_iii
in feedparser.parse(feed_iii).entries]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Here you can find my Code:**

```
import feedparser
import MySQLdb
import time
from cookielib import CookieJar

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                 user="root", # your username - SELECT * FROM mysql.user
                 passwd="****", # your password
                 db="sentimentanalysis_unicode",
                 charset="utf8") # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
cur.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8")
cur.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8")
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS feeddata_iii")

sql_iii = """CREATE TABLE feeddata_iii(III_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(III_ID),III_UnixTimesstamp integer,III_Timestamp varchar(255),III_Source varchar(255),III_Title varchar(255),III_Text TEXT,III_Link varchar(255),III_Epic varchar(255),III_CommentNr integer,III_Author varchar(255))"""

cur.execute(sql_iii)

def feed_load_iii(feed_iii):
return [(time.time(),
         entry.published,
         'iii',
         entry.title,
         entry.summary,
         entry.link,
         (entry.link.split('=cotn:')[1]).split('.L&id=')[0],
         (entry.link.split('.L&id=')[1]).split('&display=')[0],
         entry.author)
        for entry
        in feedparser.parse(feed_iii).entries]

def main():
feed_url_iii = "http://www.iii.co.uk/site_wide_discussions/site_wide_rss2.epl"

feed_iii = feed_load_iii(feed_url_iii)

print feed_iii[1][1]

for item in feed_iii:
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO feeddata_iii(III_UnixTimesstamp, III_Timestamp, III_Source, III_Title, III_Text, III_Link, III_Epic, III_CommentNr, III_Author) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",item)
db.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
while True:
    main()
    time.sleep(240)
```

If you need further information - please feel free to ask. I need your help!

*Thanks and Regards from London!*

Comment: First you need to fix your indention, now about your question you are tying to access a cell in a list which not exists (see at your `splits`), try to print or log the entry before executing the code, by that you'll see where is your problem.

Comment: Do I understand you in the right way: The error belongs to the split function in the feed_load_iii block? Is it possible to write an argument like: try: split (X) except: set value 'NULL'

Comment: It's some where in you `return` statement of `def feed_load_iii(feed_iii):`.

Comment: Do you know if a loop opportunity like *try: split (X) except: set value 'NULL'* exists?

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) but not inside a list comprehension, another option is to use a generator.

Comment: can you give me an example. I am very new to python and i am german ... so it is hard to unterstand what you mean with a generator!? A code example would be perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In essence, your program is insufficiently resilient to poorly-formatted data.

Your code makes very explicit assumptions about the structure of the data, and is unable to cope if the data is not so structured. You need to detect the cases where the data is incorrectly formatted and take some other action then.

A rather sloppy way to do this would simply trap the exception that's currently being raised which you could do with (something like)

```
try:
    feed_iii = feed_load_iii(feed_url_iii)
except IndexError:
    # do something to report or handle the data format problem
```

Comment: Have you got an Idea for the **# do something to report or handle the data format problem** ... i am very new to Python and have no idea :(

Comment: For a start, report it, than you might fix the data error rather than having to suffer it!